# print webpage into pdf file using java or javascript

Tags: java, javascript, pdf

I have requirement to convert a web page into pdf using java or javascript. This pdf should exactly look like print format of webpage. So basically I have to print the html webpage into pdf doc using java or javascript

Comment: Check this out. http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/ or you can use iText http://www.itextpdf.com/ (commercial).

Comment: iText is available as APGL or a commercial license... not just commercial.  Also, iText's HTML rendering isn't all that hot.

Comment: Implementing it urself might be too much work and I don't think there are any good free packages out there. But, you could use Applescript or programmatically access the print facility in Windows to achieve this end.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest [wkhtmltopdf](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBYQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fwkhtmltopdf%2F&ei=bqn-TPahLojQsAPXuaiwCw&usg=AFQjCNEb0ynW8pjrkwFO60-rlQ9ZVVbpzg).  It uses webkit to render HTML to PDF. Snazzy.

PS: "exactly" is a rather fickle concept in HTML.  "Pixel perfect" simply won't happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/

**But** it is **impossible** to create an **exactly** equal looking pdf. There is no support for scrollabars in PDF. especially, if the PDF should be printed.